# Error when importing in-house distribution of iPhone app into iTunes

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6

I get this error when i import distribution of my app into iTunes:

'A provisioning profile named "embedded.mobileprovision" already exists on this   computer. Do you want to replace it?'.

But import into other Mac's iTunes success!

And my "Application Requires iPhone Environment" in the info.plist is already "YES" but don't work.

Comment: Does it actually give an error? Because that looks like a question and you have to respond?

Comment: You can do one thing delete all provisioning profile from your system and then make a refresh from your xcode preferences to load the updated profiles. It seems that you have one expired or invalid profile you haven't refresh your profile.

You can delete profile from location provision /Users/<Username>/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles

Comment: @Jaques My bad. This is my first question here, and my english is not very well. Now i have edited my question.

Comment: @deoKaushal i have solved this problem by using command line: xcrun -sdk iphoneos PackageApplication -v "${RELEASE_BUILDDIR}/${APPLICATION_NAME}.app" -o "${BUILD_HISTORY_DIR}/${APPLICATION_NAME}.ipa"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might give you signing error while installing, you might try this one.

```
xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath $projectname.xcarchive -exportPath $projectname -exportFormat ipa -exportWithOriginalSigningIdentity
```

This will export your ipa along with signing with same signing identity that you have used during archiving.